Get previous results from the Allure report
With the help of the Allure report, I have managed to gather results from multiple test executions. The cumulative outcomes are visible in the Overview and Graph sections. However, I can no longer access the results of a specific earlier test run. In the Categories section, under Product defects, only the failed test cases from the most recent run are displayed. How could I search for a specific date?
I use tags, but even based on these, I cannot search for earlier results.
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
Allure.label("tag", timeStamp);

